# Play Certain Track With BackgroundAudioAgent Issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-player, background-music, background-audio

I am having an isssue about playing a certain audio among List which is being played on background. Is there any way to pass the data from app to background audio agent and, let say, play the 5th audio like Spotify does.

[The sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx) I am working on

[Another version](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Play-music-under-lock-548d2dac)

There are some information about passing data from app to agent but, I couldn't implement what is being suggested.

[Suggestion 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/10/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-2.aspx)
[image]

[Suggestion 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944(v=vs.105).aspx)
[image]

**Could you please help me to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: [AudioTrack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiotrack(v=vs.105).aspx) has `Tag` property which you can access from BAP and App, thus it can serve for communication between them. You can also use IsolatedStorageFile to pass some information - both BAP and App has access to same IsolatedStorage. All you have to do is to programm you Agent and main UI to use Tag/File.

Comment: Good but exception throws when I try to set it. Here it is; 
[link](http://1drv.ms/1cxEoVi)

Comment: I've added as an answer why you get Exception. It doesn't answer the question but hopefuly will help you a little to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  want to communicate by `Tag` property then you must be aware that, once `AudioTrack` has been created you will have to use BeginEdit as [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiotrack%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Once the track has been created using one of the AudioTrack constructors, then the BeginEdit() and EndEdit() methods must be used to update the object.

For example changing `Tag` can look like this:

```
AudioTrack track = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track;
track.BeginEdit();
track.Tag = "New Tag";
track.EndEdit();
```

(accessing by a reference is needed here).